# Akka HTTP client throws SSLHandshakeException and is unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I know this is a frequent question, but cannot find a quick solution for Akka http client.
I use Akka http client to make a request to some internal https endpoint, and I want to disable SSL, like this:

```scala
val badSslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig().mapSettings(s => s.withLoose(s.loose.withDisableHostnameVerification(true).withAcceptAnyCertificate(true).withDisableSNI(true)))
val badCtx: HttpsConnectionContext = Http().createClientHttpsContext(badSslConfig) 
// or http.setDefaultClientHttpsContext(badCtx)
http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(...), badCtx) .map { ... }
```

But it keeps throwing the exception:

```scala
Future(Failure(javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target))
```

Could anyone give some help this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working example [here](https://www.programcreek.com/scala/javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager).

```scala
    val sslContext = {
      val permissiveTrustManager: TrustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
        override def checkClientTrusted(chain: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Unit = {}
        override def checkServerTrusted(chain: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Unit = {}
        override def getAcceptedIssuers(): Array[X509Certificate] = Array.empty
      }
      val ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
      ctx.init(Array.empty, Array(permissiveTrustManager), new SecureRandom())
      ctx
    }
```

Comment: With this the request just hangs till timeout